# how to set wpf extended tookit chart line series as a top line series?

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit, lineseries

is there any way how to bring to the front any of displayed line series in my chart component?
I tried Focus(), but this do not work.
thanks

Comment: You can change their order in xaml. Or try to retrieve the drawn series and change ZIndex.

Comment: there is no such property as ZIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var series = (Series)chart.Series[0]; // you can replace 0 by a more appropriate index
series.SetValue(Panel.ZIndexProperty, 99);
```

I used an arbitrary value 99 for ZIndex, in reality you can use any value greater than 0.

[Here is the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) on this property.